# Resetting Character Array Value

Tags: c, arrays, string

I have the following declared globally

```
    char a[20] = " ";
    char b[20] = " ";
    char c[20] = " ";
    char d[20] = " ";
```

I need to set these variable to NULL in a method.So i use

```
void mymethod()
{
        a[10]=" ";
        b[10]=" ";
        c[10]=" ";
        d[10]=" ";
}
```

But the variables still retain their old value.What im i doing wrong?

Comment: This code shouldn't even compile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
char a[20] = "";
```

This is initializing an array during declaration.

Whereas

```
a[10] = "";
```

This is actually setting a value to an element in an array.

Try using

```
memset(a,0,sizeof(a));
```

To initialize your array within a function.

Comment: "This is actually setting a value to an element in an array."  No it isn't. It is not one of the valid forms of simple assignment (6.5.16.1) so this code should not even compile.

Comment: @Lundin Agree. But since OP said it is compiling I thought this is going through assigning some junk value to the 11th element in the array

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[20] = " ";
char b[20] = " ";
char c[20] = " ";
char d[20] = " ";
```

`a, b, c, d` are `const`, and cannot be changed.

if you want to set the elements of the array to 0(NULL), use memset

```
memset(a, 0, sizeof(a));
```

if you want to set variable a to NULL, you should declared `a` as pointer.

```
char *a = " ";
a = NULL;
```

Comment: i just want to use `a` to store a string.Is an array required? Like this `a="hello"`

Comment: char a[20] = " ";     strcpy(a, "hello");   now a stores `hello`

Answer (score 0):

```
char a[20] = " ";
```

Here you are intialising a `char` array named `a`

```
a[10]=" ";
```

Here you are assigning a string literal `{' ','\0'}` to the 11th char in the array a. Thats undefined behavior.

> I need to set these variable to NULL in a method.

First of all, and I know this is nitpicking, but its still important, c does not have methods. c has functions.

If you merely want to zero out an array you can do it like this (assuming your char array is global)

```
void clearString (char *string, int lenght)
{
    memset(string, '\0', lenght);
}
```

Which you could then call like this:

```
clearString(a,20);
```